# How to configure so that ng build breaks on "Unrecognized event"

Tags: angular, tsconfig

I would like that warnings of type "Unrecognized event" in Angular template files are treated as errors and breaks ng build.

How to configure tsconfig/angularCompilerOptions to achive that?

GUI shown in image is Rider.

[image]